# Problems with my first Java program

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple pounds to kilogram converter. Not sure what I'm doing wrong because it won't print out the answer. Could someone help me out.

```
public class ass10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double lbs2kg(3);
    }
    public double lbs2kg(double w){
        System.out.println(w/2.2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use some IDE that can highlight errors. And start class names with a capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete `double` or put a variable and also method `lbs2kg()` must be static
(Make it return double or a compatible type, too).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = lbs2kg(3);
}
```

Comment: Umm. there is one more problem.

Comment: @RohitJain method must be static.

Comment: @bonCodigo missing `return` ;)

Comment: @ivanovic ... and replace 
**System.out.println** with **return**

Answer (score 1):

use something like this:-

```
  double x = lbs2kg(3);
```

You are also missing the `return` in your function.

Also,

```
public static void lbs2kg(double w){
System.out.println(w/2.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want...

```
public class ass10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lbs2kg(3);
    }

    public static void lbs2kg(double w){
        System.out.println(w/2.2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For cleaner code, I'd do:

```
public class ass10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(lbs2kg(3));
    }

    public static double lbs2kg(double w){
        return w/2.2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out I'm just missing static for my method. 
Thanks for the help!